# Changing controller property in action doesn't change the view

Tags: ember.js

I am  a newbie in ember, and i've got a problem. The point is i need to create an application where almost every page depends on selected month and year, so i decided to put that property in application controller and render to application template. Right now i have:

application controller:

```
    App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    date: new Date(),
    current_date: function() {
        var d = this.get('date');
        var date = '01';
        var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = d.getFullYear();

        return {
            date: date,
            month: month,
            year: year
        };
    }.property('date'),

    actions: {
        previousMonth: function() {
            var date = this.get('date');
            date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
            this.set('date', date);
            console.log(this.get('date'));
        },
        nextMonth: function() {
            var date = this.get('date');
            date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
            this.set('date', date);
            console.log(this.get('date'));
        }
    }
});
```

application view:

```
 App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    date: function() {
        var raw_date = this.get('controller.current_date');
        return raw_date.month + " " + raw_date.year;
    }.property('controller.current_date')
});
```

and application.js.emblem

```
.date_selector
    h2#month
        a click="previousMonth" href="#" prev
        current_date
        a click="nextMonth" href="#" next
outlet
```

Default render is ok. But when i click next or previous month nothing changes, but console shows that the value has actually changed. Do i miss something?

Comment: So i guess it just doesn't know how to detect `Date` changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `new Date()` isn't an Ember object, when you call `date.setMonth`, Ember doesn't know it has changed. What you could try is to manually trigger a property change by calling `this.notifyPropertyChange('date')`, and then you shouldn't need to call `this.set('date', date)` again.

For example:

```
previousMonth: function() {
    var date = this.get('date');
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
    this.notifyPropertyChange('date');
    console.log(this.get('date'));
}
```

Or you could, as you found, create a `new Date()` object and set that as the current `date` property.

```
previousMonth: function() {
    var date = this.get('date');
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth()-1);
    this.set('date', new Date(date));
    console.log(this.get('date'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a problem. The reason is date.setMonth and this.set('date', date) don't count as a change in property. I guess it thinks that it's still same object and doesn't update. Solution is to create new Date variable based on date data and set it through this.set('date', new_variable). I still think it's weird.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not updating due to the `toString()` function of `date object`.

Refer to this example [here](https://ember-twiddle.com/bb759103e456bbfcde02)

`It simply returns a string and not an Object's property to the template`. That's why Ember is not able to update the template

Comment: I've tried through console `toString()` and it actually returns every change been made to date. I guess only source code of ember holds the answer.